# Can I ask personal Drupal questions \ Opinion based questions in the Meta?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask personal Drupal/Drush related questions or questions that some mods might see the answer upon them as opinion-based or off-topic questions in the Meta?

An example for a personal question would be:

> Why When I install composer on Windows 7/10, I need to set its Path
>   variable so it would work, but when I install another program, like
>   Google Chrome, I don't?

One can philosophize if there is even any connection, but for me it's the fact that non Linux users must have some fundamental understanding of the Environment Variable concept to work with them efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)...

> Meta Drupal Answers is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Drupal Answers rather than discussing Drupal itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...
>
> - ...**Drupal Answers users to communicate with each other** about Drupal Answers (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
> - ...**Drupal Answers users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company** (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and
> - ...**Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community** (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network)

I think that's pretty self explanatory - please only ask questions on meta that fulfil one or more of those criteria, questions about Drupal itself, or non Drupal-related technical questions like your example, will inevitably wind up closed.

If you need to talk about stuff that isn't appropriate for a question on the main site, there's always chat. There's also a [previous meta question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/where-to-ask-how-to-questions/3342) on roughly the same topic which has some good suggestions for alternatives.

As an aside - with a bit of fleshing out, I think your example question would probably be a good fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)